# GCM registration id not starting with APA

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using **GCM** and in some cases the devices are getting strange registration id

To get the id I use:
GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context)

- *Normal behavior* **"APA...."**
- *Strange behavior 1* **"|ID|0|APA...."**
- *Strange behavior 2* **"|ID|0|something_else:APA...."**

The problem is that i can't send notifications to the malformed ids and i have to sanitize them, but it would be preferable to have them allways wellformed

Comment: This is a strange behavior. Are you seeing any patterns where you receive them?

Comment: This [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355586/do-android-gcm-registration-ids-always-start-with-apa)  states that registration Ids does not always start with APA. Might help.

Comment: @AL. the pattern that I have found is |ID|0| |ID|1| and |ID|2| as prefixes. 
noogui All devices are Android

Comment: matias - I meant are you seeing any patterns on where you're receiving this kind of behavior? Specific android dvices or models or os versions. Stuff like that.

Comment: No, I can't see any patterns. And in addition, for some devices I get sometimes the normal behavior and other times the strange ones